# How to create a file upload in a modal window (jQuery)

Tags: jquery-ui, file-upload, redactor, modal-window

I want to create a text filed. When focus or click it, a file upload modal window will be showed (like file upload modal window of the redactor - http://imperavi.com/redactor/)
The return file name will showed in the text filed.
How can I do it ? Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 4):

Have you try jQuery File Upload ? File Upload widget with multiple file selection, drag&drop support and progress bar for jQuery. Supports cross-domain, chunked and resumable file uploads. Works with any server-side platform (PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Java, Node.js, Go etc.) that supports standard HTML form file uploads.

Check this : http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html